# Как распарсить Json строку

Tags: c#, json, webclient

Есть следующий JSON:

```
{
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "XCD": {
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "XCD"
    },
    "EUR": {
      "currencyName": "Euro",
      "currencySymbol": "€",
      "id": "EUR"
    }
  }
}
```

Не могу понять как распарсить строку, так что-бы все значения id попали в массив(то бишь имена валют).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Какая всё-таки удобная закрывашка у нас теперь есть. )

Comment: @AK Есть такое)) Это прям самый распространенный вопрос по JSON, а люди все ленятся, да ленятся...